# USB disabled when ethernet is plugged in

Tags: usb, keyboard, ethernet, ethernet-port

I'm using a wireless keyboard, it works fine with the raspberry pi, but when I plugin my ethernet my keyboard no longer functions. I can't enter any keys or anything. Any ideas?

No usb hub involved.

Comment: Tested with wifi card, same deal.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a Powered USB Hub. Sounds like a power issue.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out, I changed to a different plug and it worked. Guess my other plug wasn't outputting enough power or current

Comment: You're welcome - `Sounds like a power issue`. If you found my answer useful, please mark answered. Thx